# Omniauth-Ldap Ruby Invalid Credentials

Tags: ruby, ldap, omniauth, credentials

I am student from salzburg.
I am trying to create a login possibility via ldap with omnitauth-ldap, when I enter username and password it is redirecting to `/auth/failure` with `message=invalid_credentials` and I don't know why. Facebook-, Twitter- and BrowserID-Login is working.

- Ruby-Version: 1.9.2
- Omni-Auth-Version: 1.0.1
- Omniauth-Ldap-Version: 1.0.2

### omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :browser_id
  provider :facebook, '34234234234', '23423421234123412342134'
  provider :twitter, 'dfgsdfgsdfg', '2334sadfasdfasdf'
  provider :ldap, :title => 'FH-Authentifizierung',
  :host => 'denise.core.fh-salzburg.ac.at',
  :port => 636,
  :method => :plain,
  :base => 'o=fh-salzburg.ac.at,o=FHS',
  :uid => 'uid',
  :password => "password",
  :try_sasl => false,
  :bind_dn => "anonymous"
end
```

### users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to request.referer, :notice => "Herzlich Willkommen!"
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to request.referer, :notice => "Du wurdest erfolgreich abgemeldet!"
  end
end
```

### server-output

```
Started POST "/auth/ldap/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-03 21:59:35 +0100
Started GET "/auth/failure?message=ldap_error" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-03 21:59:35 +0100
Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-03 21:59:35 +0100
Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-03 21:59:35 +0100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [omniauth-ldap code](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-ldap/blob/master/lib/omniauth-ldap/adaptor.rb) you will see that bind_dn and password are used for authentication, so they need to be valid. If you want anonymous access omit those two parameters, or set :allow_anonymous to true.